# Can't find support drawable after update to 24.1.1

Tags: android-support-library

I update support library version to 24.1.1 and now Studio cant find support recourses:

```
Error:(9, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha').
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.